# How do I get this math to calculate correctly

Tags: ruby

I get this result:

```
8.01 - 8.0 #=> 0.009999999999999787
```

I want my answer to be `0.01`. What can I do to fix this? How can I get this to happen? I guess this is float math. Is this due to floating point precision?

Comment: Rationals are good for this: `(8.01r - 8r).to_f`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Ruby's arbitrary-precision decimal data type, `BigDecimal`:

```
BigDecimal.new("8.01") - BigDecimal.new("8") # => 0.1e-1
```

Comment: How do I convert scientific notation back to a number?

Comment: @Jwan622 you can use `to_s('F')` to convert the value to a string using 
"floating point notation".

Comment: Thanks a lot man!